# PHP - using microtime() to measure CPU usage of a function/code block

Tags: php, cpu-usage, microtime

I tried using it like this:

```
$now = microtime(true); 
// cpu expensive code here
echo microtime(true) - $now;
```

but regardless of what code I enter between these statements, I alwasy get almost the same results, something like `3.0994415283203E-6`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting in a `sleep(5);` call and ensure that the result changes.  The time should be at least five seconds.

Comment: that works it seems. I get `4.9997820854187`

Comment: Wow! PHP is fast! It evaluates `sleep(5);` in less than 5 seconds!

Comment: Welcome to [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better solution.  Run the code multiple times to average out the operation:

```
$runs = 500;

$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < $runs; $i++) {
    //cpu expensive code here
}
$end = microtime(true);
$elapsed = number_format($end - $start, 4);
$one = number_format(($end - $start) / 500, 7);
echo "500 runs in $elapsed seconds, average of $one seconds per call";
```

Comment: I don't think 5 decimal places will be enough in this case.

Comment: Then add a 6th or 7th.  But I doubt any truly "expensive" code would run in less than e^-5...

Comment: would you consider `0.0005` too much? the problem I'm trying to solve is a shared host that tells me a script of mine is using too much cpu, but don't know which part of it :(

Comment: @Alex: it's completely context dependent.  Do you know that there is a bottleneck?  Or are you just checking because you think it might be slow?

Comment: I'm checking all the functions that I suspect they use more cpu.

Comment: @Alex: but is that because it's slow, or because you want to make it as efficient as possible?

Comment: the host tells me it's slow :) yes I want to make it as efficient as possible

Comment: @Alex: Then start by profiling the entire script first.  Then you have a baseline to compare to.  Otherwise you'll have a hard time determining what to do, and what effect it will have...

Answer (score 3):

`3.0994415283203E-6` equates to `0.0000030994415283203`.

The `E-6` tells you to move the decimal point left six places.  `E+6` would mean the opposite.  As @deceze mentioned, this is called scientific notation.

If you're doing a performance test, it's a good idea to put the code into a 100000 or so iteration loop, and then divide the resulting time by 100000.  That way you get a more accurate average.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's just that the code you're timing really only takes a fraction of a second to run.

If you want to prove it, [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `microtime()` without the optional argument, but you say you are, so I am not 100% sure.

What is the output of this:

```
$now = microtime(true);
sleep(1);
echo microtime(true) - $now;
```

Comment: The 'true' is the optional argument.

Answer (score 0):

PHP always amazes me with how fast it is. Your code seems to be right. Maybe your code is really only taking 3 milliseconds.

You could try making a long loop, something like this:

```
$x=0;
while ($x<1000000)
  {
  $x++;
  }
```

Add this code inside of your timer. For me, looping 1 million times usually takes about 1/2 second. See if this changes your time.

Comment: why not use `sleep` or `usleep` to delay a measurable amount rather than guessing?

Comment: @ ircmaxell - I don't know. It doesn't matter. This was just the first thing that came to my mind.